# Python - How to Automatically Assign Variables to Numerous Inputs

Tags: python, variables

So i have a program where the user enters in a few details e.g name, place etc. However, when i collect these details, they are all assigned to the variable name that i gave to the input collector (e.g input =). But i need to process these variables into a specific order (its a bibliography generator fyi). However i need to assign each of the instances of inputs into different variables without having basically the same code over and over again, but i couldn't think of a way to do that.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: show us some code so we can help you...

Comment: Post whatever code you already have and we can try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solve that problem in the past:

1) Store the data in an ordered dictionary.

2) Store the data in an object and use a function that returns the data in the order specified.

Comment: I've assumed that you have key/value pairs whose order is important.